# how to use Zeitgeist activity logger

Tags: zeitgeist

My daughter uses Ubuntu and I want to WATCH her activity not lock it down.  I'd rather give her the freedom to make choices over filtering her content.
Google search has turned up  Zeitgeist as a logger for Ubuntu (using 14.04) but the Activity Journal doesn't appear to show any activity.
Additionally all screenshots I see show a checkmark in the bottom right corner (checked for logging, x for not logging) and I don't see that.
Please help this n00b figure out what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the top right corner and click on the gears icon:
   [image]
2. Press <kbd>System Settings</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Security and Privacy</kbd>
4. Ensure the button is ON
5. Turn all check-marks on

That's it!  Zeitgeist is now recording all checked activities.

For more information and how to analyse the data, head to http://zeitgeist-project.com/experience/ and especially look at "Activity Journal" which is a UI to the back-end sqlite database (you can also just run queries on the database itself, or have it copied over somewhere else for later analysis)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply on this question.  I have (already) followed the steps you have listed but I still dont see activity in the Zeitgeist Activity Journal.  Everything is checked to on.